# Emacs/Matlab: Auto-indentation of functions inside classdef/methods block

Tags: matlab, emacs, indentation

I have encountered several problems with auto-indentation in Emacs (v.24.3.1, matlab.el v.3.3.2) of matlab files that uses the classdef-style object-oriented code specification.

In the first example files below, the section starting with the line marked `%%%%% (1)` is indented one step too much. The incorrect indentation continues until the function-closing `end`.

In the second file, the functions at `%%%%% (2)` and `%%%%% (3)` are indented incrementally one step too much. Here, the incorrect indentation continues until the methods-closing `end`. (However, this particular problem disappears if I remove the comment at the preceding function-closing `end`.)

There is also a syntax-highlighting issue (not shown below) where the function head `function modulus = get.Modulus(obj)` are not recognized as function heads.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a fix? Are my problems configuration problems, or does this correspond to a bug in matlab.el?

I have reduced my .emacs to contain only the following lines:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs/matlab-emacs")
(require 'matlab-load)
(setq matlab-indent-function-body t)
(setq matlab-functions-have-end t)
```

TestUnit.m:

```
classdef TestUnit
    enumeration
        mm (1)
        pixels (2)
        in (4)
    end

    methods
        function s=asstring(p)
        %ASSTRING Return string version of TestUnit object.

            [a,b]=enumeration(p);
                s=b{find(a==p,1,'first')}; %%%%% (1)
            end
    end
end
```

TensileData.m:

```
classdef TensileData
    properties
        Material = 'carbon steel';
        SampleNumber = 0;
        Stress
        Strain
    end

    properties (Dependent)
        Modulus
    end

    methods
        function td = TensileData(material,samplenum,stress,strain)
            if nargin > 0
                td.Material = material;
                td.SampleNumber = samplenum;
                td.Stress = stress;
                td.Strain = strain;
            end
        end % TensileData
    end % methods

    methods
        function obj = set.Material(obj,material)
            if ~(strcmpi(material,'aluminum') ||...
                 strcmpi(material,'stainless steel') ||...
                 strcmpi(material,'carbon steel'))
                error('Material must be aluminum, stainless steel, or carbon steel')
            end
            obj.Material = material;
        end % Material set function

            function modulus = get.Modulus(obj) %%%%%% (2)
                ind = find(obj.Strain > 0); % Find nonzero strain
                modulus = mean(obj.Stress(ind)./obj.Strain(ind));
            end % Modulus get function

                function obj = clear(obj)       %%%%%%% (3)
                % Another test function
                    obj.Stress=[]; obj.Strain=[];
                end
    end % methods
end % classdef
```

The following was generated by starting `emacs -Q TestUnit.m` followed by `M-x octave-mode` and `C-x h M-C\`. The following keywords had syntax highlighting: `end`, `function`, `asstring`, but not `classdef`, `enumeration` nor `methods`.

```
classdef TestUnit
enumeration
mm (1)
pixels (2)
in (4)
end

methods
function s=asstring(p)
  %ASSTRING Return string version of TestUnit object.
  a=enumeration(p);
  s=b{find(a==p,1,'first')};
end
end
end
```

Comment: I've tracked down the %%%%% (1) example to the dual use of 'enumeration' as keyword and function name. It may be possible to fix this by modifying matlab-mcos-regexp, defined on line 1417 of matlab.el, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, the built-in Octave-mode seems to indent your second example correctly.  On the first example it also gets caught in your `enumeration(p)` call.  I have a tentative patch to octave.el which fixes the indentation for your example, but not knowing much about Matlab/Octave I have no idea where your "enumeration" function comes from, so it's hard to know what would The Right Fix.  Is it a standard function, or can you define it yourself?  Does this also apply to other keywords (e.g. could there also be a "classdef" function)?

Comment: Hmm...could you elaborate on that? If I switch to octave-mode (delete all references to matlab-mode in my .emacs file and add what's described in 
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Using-Octave-Mode.html to my .emacs), the indentation for e.g. classdef, properties, etc. does not work at all.

Comment: To try out Octave mode, lyou shouldn't need to delete anything in your .emacs: just do `M-x octave-mode`.  I don't have 24.3 here right now to confirm your problem, but what I described applies to Emacs-24.5 and I can't remember making any significant changes to Octave mode's indentation code betwen 24.3 and 24.5.  Could you try `emacs -Q foo.m` and then copy-pasting your sample code and `C-x h M-C-\ ` to reindent it?

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I couldn't find how to preserve indentation in a comment, so I added your example to my original question. There is no syntax highlighting at all on `classdef`, etc. It kind of looks like my octave-mode doesn't recognize classdef-style code.

Comment: I can't seen to find a version number for `octave-mode`? Does it have one or are you saying that it follows `emacs-version`?

Comment: To answer your `enumeration`-question: No, I don't think there should be another case where a keyword can also by used as a function name. I thought it was forbidden, but apparently not...

Comment: Hmm, indeed, it looks like support for clasdef was added in May 2013, i.e. between 24.3 and 24.4.  And yes, octave-mode is maintained as part of Emacs so it doesn't come with its own version number.  Thanks for your answer on "enumeration", I'll see about adding support for it to octave-mode.

Comment: I have just installed a new version of octave.el into Emacs's "master" branch which should fix the problem with `enumeration(p)`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I'll try to download and install 24.5 to see if that solves my problem (bar enumeration, which will have to wait until 24.6 I presume).

Comment: Right, tho 24.6 will be called 25.1.  In the mean time you can work around the problem with `enumeration` by wrapping the call within parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, I've also figured out that the `enumeration` case is so rare I can indent it manually ;).